# How to find the variable in the exercise?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this algebraic exercise:

> $x^{x^5}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[75]{125}}$, find $x$

Then, my development was:

$1) (x^{x^5})^5 = (\frac{1}{\sqrt[75]{5^3}})^5$

$2) (x^{x^5})^5 = (\frac{1}{5^{1/25}})^5$

$3) (x^{5x^5}) = (\frac{1}{5^{1/5}})$

$4) (x^{5})^{x^5} = (\frac{1}{5})^{\frac{1}{5}}$

This was my last step, I do not really know what I should do here and I'm also supposed to solve it in 1 - 2 minutes maximum.

Comment: You're doing good, even if it's not a very "traditional" way of extracting $x$... For the sake of clarity, let's say you note $y=x^5$, and $u=\frac15$ Equation 4) says $y^y=u^u$. Now you have to study function $f:x\mapsto x^x=e^{x\ln x}$, to see if $y=u$ is the only solution (it's not).

Comment: MathLover, is about that property, what is it ?

Comment: Nicolas, how you know that if $y^y = u^u$, then $y = u$ ?

Comment: @Mattiu If $y=u$ then $y^y=u^u$. So $x^5 = 1/5$ is one of the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x^{5})^{x^5} = (\frac{1}{5})^{\frac{1}{5}}$$

One solution is $$ x^5 = 1/5$$

$$ x=(1/5)^{1/5}$$

Comment: I think that the implication is reversed.

Comment: @MathLover is correct, within the real numbers only there is more solution($e^{\frac15W\left(-\frac{\ln(5)}{5}\right)}\approx 0.892$)